# How i get the Json Data where send with Ajax?

Tags: php, extjs

how i get my Json Data where i send via Ajax to my php file?

i have the following test object:

```
var test = {"tlknummer":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
```

and send them like this:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "app/view/main/saveInDatabase.php",
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: test, 
    success: function( r ) {        
        console.log("Senden erfolgreich" + r.responseText);
    },
    failure: function( r ) {
        console.log("Senden fehlgeschlagen" + r.responseText);
    }
});
```

in the php file i would like to get access on them like this:

```
$data = $_POST['tlknummer'];
```

but they said always:     Undefined index: tlknummer

whats wrong? how i get access on the JsonObject i have send?

Thank for help!

Comment: What does the line `foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) echo("Post key ".$k." is ".$v);` give you?

Comment: I get back an empty string ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access data as

```
$data = $_POST['tlknummer'];
```

then you need to send it as params, i.e.:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "app/view/main/saveInDatabase.php",
    method: 'POST',
    params: test, 
    success: function( r ) {        
        console.log("Senden erfolgreich" + r.responseText);
    },
    failure: function( r ) {
        console.log("Senden fehlgeschlagen" + r.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works!!! But without JSON.stringify

For this reason is it enough like this var test = {"tlknummer":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};

If the json object is bigger, you can spend so everything.
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) echo("Post key ".$k." is ".$v);

Answer (score 0):

You are sending **Javascript Object**. Here, you need to do **convert the javascript object in JSON**.

```
var test = JSON.stringify({"tlknummer":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"});
```

and also add `dataType : "json"` inside the **AJAX call**

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: "app/view/main/saveInDatabase.php",
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: test, 
    dataType : "json",
    success: function( r ) {        
        console.log("Senden erfolgreich" + r.responseText);
    },
    failure: function( r ) {
        console.log("Senden fehlgeschlagen" + r.responseText);
    }
});
```

I think, It will work..

Comment: It doesn´t work, same problem as above :(
Either purely my old problem or an empty string as the solution from Alexander